# Pronunciation of /jɪr/ and /ji:r/ in American accent

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics

In American accent, is /jɪr/ and /ji:r/ pronounced the same?

Comment: Are you aware that the tense-lax distinction is neutralized before /r/? And that vowel length is not phonemic here so isn't to be used between slashes?

Comment: @tchrist I didn't know about it. But after some research, I can infer that what you mean in via the above comment is there's no distinction at all (or it is blurred)?

Comment: It varies at the individual and group levels; you find different versions of the neutralization in different lects. And some variation in the phonemes used in certain lexemes, as well. When a contrast becomes hard to make or hear in a phonetic context, different people adopt different ways of making the necessary distinctions, but don't pay much attention to maintaining internal phonological consistency, which is only worthwhile when it predicts accurately. And in the middle of a sound change, nothing predicts accurately.

Comment: Some Americans pronounce *year* as /jɪr/ and some as /ji:r/. We don't distinguish between these pronunciations — they're allophones in American English. But if you ask Americans whether the vowel in *year* is the one in *bid* or the one in *bead*, I expect that you'll get different answers from different people.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are reading this question:

> Tense–lax neutralization refers to a neutralization, in a particular phonological context in a particular language, of the normal distinction between tense and lax vowels.

> In some varieties of English, this occurs in particular before /ŋ/ and (in rhotic dialects) before coda /r/ (that is, /r/ followed by a consonant or at the end of a word); it also occurs, to a lesser extent, before tautosyllabic /ʃ/.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_vowels#Tense%E2%80%93lax_neutralization

Kudo to @tchrist's comment above.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Would be better to put this in your actual post! :)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike many languages, English permits the palatal glide /j/ to occur before the vowels /ɪ/ and /i(:)/. Setting aside the issue of which of these vowels occurs in *ear* and *year,* they are not pronounced the same because *year* starts with the consonant /j/ (so we say “a year”) and *ear* starts with a vowel (and so we say “an ear”). Likewise, “east” and “yeast” differ in that one starts with /i(:)/ and the other starts with /ji(:)/.